# How to install cuml in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cuml

i want to install the CUML in my notebook instance. I have tried

conda create -n rapids-23.06 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  
rapids=23.06 python=3.10 cudatoolkit=11.8

and

docker pull rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04

docker run --runtime nvidia --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 8786:8786 
rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04

Both of them not working for me, as after everything complete, it still shows module error.